# How to root element dynamically provide in cts:search using Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

After using the below mentioned Xquery I am getting the output correctly.

```
let $element :="Name"
let $value := "Antony"
let $op :=  cts:search(//root, cts:element-value-query( xs:QName($element),$value))
return $op
```

But I am getting error while using "**root**" value in variable. Please suggest me, if any other options?

```
let $element := "Name"
let $value := "Antony"
let $root := "root"
let $op := cts:search(//$root, cts:element-value-query( xs:QName($element),$value))
return $op
```

Error :

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNSEARCHABLE: cts:search(fn:collection()/descendant-or-self::node()/"root", cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("","Name"), "Antony", ("lang=en"), 1)) -- Expression is unsearchable

Stack Trace
At line 16 column 23:

In xdmp:eval("(:&#10; let $uri := cts:element-value-query( xs:QName(&quot;file...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>8922589838473153050</database><root>/marklogic/poc/</r...</options>)

$element := "Name"
$value := "Antony"
$root := "root"

14. let $value := "Antony"
15. let $root :="root"
16. **let $op := cts:search(//$root, cts:element-value-query( xs:QName($element),$value))**
17. return $op
```

Example data:

```
<root processtype="sample">
  <title series="hk">
    <Name>Antony</Name>
  </title>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use the `$root` value in that way.. in order to match the `$root` value you have to do the following `//root[. = $root]`

```
let $element :="Name"
let $value := "Antony"
let $root :="root"
let $op :=  cts:search(//root[. = $root], cts:element-value-query( xs:QName($element),$value))
return $op
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , but I tried this query  only got " your query returned an empty sequence " so can you help any better way.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data in order to see were the miss?

Comment: I have added sample XML below for your perusal .<root processtype="sample">
<title series="hk" >
 <Name>Antony</Name>
     </title>
</root>

Comment: You can notice from your sample, the `root` element does not have data to be compared with. So you can search for the attribute data as the following code `//root[@processtype = $root]`

Comment: Also you can modify your `cts:search` query in order to search in a specific root element. For example, `cts:search(//root, cts:and-query((cts:element-value-query( xs:QName($element),$value), cts:element-value-query( xs:QName("root"),$root))))`.. this can be done be and query for two element value queries

Comment: Thanks , Its very helpful.

Comment: @Antony if this answer satisfied you, could you please mark it as Accepted? That gives credit to Khadija Qaraqe and lets others know you don't need more help.